# How to make a button bigger when pressed? (Android Studios)

Tags: java, android, xml, button, pressed

I'm working on an app in Android studios and would like my customised button to get bigger when pressed and go back to the default defined state when released. I wrote an xml file to define my button but it didn't work. Here's my xml file for the custom button:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/play_button_pressedhdpi"
        android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/play_button_defaulthdpi"
        android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/play_button_defaulthdpi" />
</selector>
```

This doesn't seem to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:

I just tried the following code as mentioned in the first answer below:

```
button1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            {
                //sendMessage("Key1\n");
                lp.width = 200;
                lp.height = 200;
                button1.setLayoutParams(lp);
            }

            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                lp.width=90;
                lp.height=90;
                button1.setLayoutParams(lp);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

This makes sense but didn't work for some reason.

Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: you can have an onClick on the button and adjust the buttons button.getLayoutParams().height = newHeight and button.getLayoutParams().width = newWidth

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was finally able to solve the problem. I created two separate images of two different sizes and used the setOnTouchListener() to assign the appropriate image to the button for each of the states `ACTION_DOWN` and `ACTION_UP` in the following manner:

```
button1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            {
                float x = (float) 1.25;
                float y = (float) 1.25;

                button1.setScaleX(x);
                button1.setScaleY(y);
                button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blue_220);

                return true;
            }

            else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
            {
                float x = 1;
                float y = 1;

                button1.setScaleX(x);
                button1.setScaleY(y);
                button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blue_206);

            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Result as desired.

Answer (score 0):

I use MotiovEvent in this way to resize my button:

```
button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams) b.getLayoutParams();
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        sendMessage("key1\n");
        lp.width=140;
        lp.height=140;
        button.setLayoutParams(lp);
    }
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        lp.width=90;
        lp.height=90;
        button.setLayoutParams(lp);
    }
    return false;
    }
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, I tried your solution but it didn't work for me. When I press the button, the app stops working and crashes. Any fix for that? Also, what is the `sendMessage()` for and is `b` in the `b.getLayoutParams()` button in your code?

Comment: Yep i copy that from my project, sorry, use only what you need to resize button, if the app crash again i need log to understand the problem.

Comment: The log doesn't say much , there are no errors in the code but as I press the button which has the `onTouchListener()` on it, the app crashes. Do i need to import any packages in order to use the `onTouchListener()`?